# Drag'n'Drop doesn't work in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, drag-and-drop

I'm on Mac OS X 10.8 and I'm using VirtualBox with Ubuntu 12.4 as guest. After install "Guest additions" Drag'n'Drop was working.

But since I install "additional drivers" and reboot the system, it does't work anymore.

Do you have a solution ?

In Settings>General>Advanced I tried Drag'n'Drop "Bidirectionnal" and "Host to Guest"

Comment: Are you sure that the guest additions are still installed correctly since you installed the extra drivers?

Comment: I re-installed, re-checked the options and now it seems to work. Tanks !